# How do I push from my Master VC to a second one on the left side, before showing the Detail VC on the right?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using the simple Master/Detail split view template in Xcode 7, and want the user to start with a high level Master VC with major categories, then choose one and drill down to individual items - still on the left side - and then show the detail VC on the right side when they choose a row on the left from the second Master VC.  So, I added a second Master view controller in the storyboard (called MasterL2ViewController) that sits between the first Master view controller and the Detail View Controller.  When the app initially starts in landscape mode, I see the Master controller on the left side and the detail controller on the right side.  I populate the first MasterViewController with some rows in its table view, and when the user taps one, it replaced the detail controller on the right side with the second Master VC.  The app works, no errors, and pulls and displays data fine, but I want that second Master VC to show on the left side instead of on the right (Detail) side.  It should use the standard navigation controller to go back to the main/first Master VC.  Hope I explained that well... could someone tell me how I can get it to push that second Master VC on the left instead of the right?  Thanks.

Screenshot of storyboard:

[image]

Here's my prepareForSegue code.  The segue between MasterViewController and MasterL2ViewController is called showLevel2.  (Segue from there to Detail VC is showDetail.)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showLevel2" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            print("indexPath=\(indexPath)")
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! Level2ViewController
            controller.mainIndexPath = indexPath
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot about the Adaptive Segue setting in Interface Builder, so changed it from "Show Detail (Replace)" to "Show (Push)", which got me part of the way... it now shows on the left side, but there's no back button to go back to the first Master VC.  Any ideas there?  https://i.imgur.com/4S8xc9T.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely clear on how you want your app to look but I think you should push other view controllers onto the one MasterViewController and forget the second.  Not sure if I am allowed to include links but I learned a lot from this tutorial.  Going through these tutorials really is a good way to accumulate knowledge.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/81879/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-1

Think MasterViewController where they say Iphone. Also you have a lot of navigation controllers. ;')

Comment: Thanks for this... turned out I had two problems:
(1) The Adaptive Segue setting had to be "Show" not "Show Detail"
(2) I had that extra Navigation Controller... got rid of that, connected up the Segue, and it works perfect.  Thanks!
https://i.imgur.com/uhYYj4C.png